# problems with hook react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am creating a step and I am using a hook to paint but it gives me this problem that if I am in 3, all the others paint me for example 4, 5, etc and I do not want that

```
export default function Registration() {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(3)
      return (
    <div className="flex">
      <div className="flex flex-col justify-center">
        <div className="w-1 h-16 flex justify-center font-bold items-center">
          1
        </div>
        <div className="w-1 h-8 flex justify-center font-bold items-end">2</div>
        <div className="w-1 h-16 flex justify-center font-bold items-end">
          3
        </div>
        <div className="w-1 h-16 flex justify-center font-bold items-end">
          4
        </div>
        <div className="w-1 h-16 flex justify-center font-bold items-end">
          5
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="w-10">
        {current === 1 ? (
          <div className="relative flex justify-center items-end">
            <div className="h-5 w-5 bg-cyan rounded-full absolute z-1"></div>
            <div className="w-1 h-10 bg-cyan"></div>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div className="relative flex justify-center items-end">
            <div className="h-5 w-5 bg-cyan rounded-full absolute z-1">
              <BiCheck />
            </div>
            <div className="w-1 h-10 bg-cyan"></div>
          </div>
        )}
        {current === 2 ? (
          <div className="relative flex justify-center items-end">
            <div className="h-5 w-5 cirlce rounded-full absolute z-1" />
            <div className="w-1 h-16 cirlce"></div>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div className="relative flex justify-center items-end">
            <div className="h-5 w-5 bg-cyan cirlce rounded-full absolute z-1">
              <BiCheck />
            </div>
            <div className="w-1 h-16 bg-cyan" />
          </div>
        )}
        {current === 3 ? (
          <div className="relative flex justify-center items-end">
            <div className="h-5 w-5 cirlce rounded-full absolute z-1" />
            <div className="w-1 h-16 cirlce"></div>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div className="relative flex justify-center items-end">
            <div className="h-5 w-5 bg-cyan rounded-full absolute z-1">
              <BiCheck />
            </div>
            <div className="w-1 h-16  bg-cyan" />
          </div>
        )}
        {current === 4 ? (
          <div className="relative flex justify-center items-end">
            <div className="h-5 w-5 cirlce rounded-full absolute z-1" />
            <div className="w-1 h-16 cirlce"></div>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div className="relative flex justify-center items-end">
            <div className="h-5 w-5 bg-cyan rounded-full absolute z-1">
              <BiCheck />
            </div>
            <div className="w-1 h-16 bg-cyan" />
          </div>
        )}
        {current === 5 ? (
          <div className="relative flex justify-center items-end">
            <div className="h-5 w-5 cirlce rounded-full absolute z-1" />
            <div className="w-1 h-16 bg-dark-15"></div>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div className="relative flex justify-center items-end">
            <div className="h-5 w-5  bg-cyan rounded-full absolute z-1">
              <BiCheck />
            </div>
            <div className="w-1 h-16 bg-cyan" />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

the problem is that when I change for example the `useState(3)` it shows me like this:

[image]

when they should be 3, 4, and 5 they should be gray

and I wanted to ask how I can change through a button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your current sample you only check if it is equal.

To check if it is equal or more you need to change `current === 1` to `current >= 1`

To change the `current value you need to use the` setter` you set for the state like this

```
<button onClick={() => setCurrent(4)}>Set to 4</button>
```

(This is a very static way to do it but just to demonstrate how it is done)

To make it a bit more dynamic you can add a function to do it

```
const changeCurrnet = (dir) => {
    const tempCurrent = dir === "up" ? current + 1 : current - 1 
    setCurrent(tempCurrent )
}

<button onClick={() => changeCurrnet("up")}>Increase</button>
<button onClick={() => changeCurrnet("down")}>Decrease</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, a question: how can I make it change through two buttons, one to return and the other to next?

Comment: @Daniel Abrego Not sure I understood your comment, do you mean that you want to change the `current` with a button?

Comment: If I want to change useState (3) for other numbers with a button because as it is a step, I would like two buttons to go one by one, I don't know if it explains me well?

Comment: @Daniel Abrego See my updated answer, let me know if it solves your question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can not figure out the problem because you are doing too many redundant elements in conditional rendering. For example, the first element :

```
{current === 1 ? (
          <div className="relative flex justify-center items-end">
            <div className="h-5 w-5 bg-cyan rounded-full absolute z-1"></div>
            <div className="w-1 h-10 bg-cyan"></div>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div className="relative flex justify-center items-end">
            <div className="h-5 w-5 bg-cyan rounded-full absolute z-1">
              <BiCheck />
            </div>
            <div className="w-1 h-10 bg-cyan"></div>
          </div>
        )}
```

You are using the same 3 divs inside both of the states, you can reduce it to:

```
<div className="relative flex justify-center items-end">
        <div className="h-5 w-5 bg-cyan rounded-full absolute z-1"></div>
        {(current != 1) && (<BiCheck />)}          
        <div className="w-1 h-10 bg-cyan"></div>
</div>
```

After this, debugging can be much easier. So, let's focus on the main problem, you need the current, and below circles to light. You are checking only for the equality, which makes the circle light if and only if the state equals its index. If you want to make it the index and all greater indices, then you need to check for `>=`  not `===`.
Your final code may look like:

```
<div className="relative flex justify-center items-end">
        <div className="h-5 w-5 bg-cyan rounded-full absolute z-1"></div>
        {(current >= 1) && (<BiCheck />)}          
        <div className="w-1 h-10 bg-cyan"></div>
</div>
<div className="relative flex justify-center items-end">
        <div className="h-5 w-5 bg-cyan rounded-full absolute z-1"></div>
        {(current >= 2) && (<BiCheck />)}          
        <div className="w-1 h-10 bg-cyan"></div>
</div>
<div className="relative flex justify-center items-end">
        <div className="h-5 w-5 bg-cyan rounded-full absolute z-1"></div>
        {(current >= 3) && (<BiCheck />)}          
        <div className="w-1 h-10 bg-cyan"></div>
</div>
<div className="relative flex justify-center items-end">
        <div className="h-5 w-5 bg-cyan rounded-full absolute z-1"></div>
        {(current >= 4) && (<BiCheck />)}          
        <div className="w-1 h-10 bg-cyan"></div>
</div>
<div className="relative flex justify-center items-end">
        <div className="h-5 w-5 bg-cyan rounded-full absolute z-1"></div>
        {(current >= 5) && (<BiCheck />)}          
        <div className="w-1 h-10 bg-cyan"></div>
</div>
```

To change using a button, you can then create an event listener on the button to change the state, and react will render the elements again depending on the newly changed state.